# Accessing Controller from Views in Emeber

Tags: ember.js

I am building a visualization app using d3 and ember.

Inside the template i have declared a view like this

`{{view 'myview'}}`
 where i have defined function to render the charts.
I want to trigger these functions on data change in the controller using observes property.
I know that all the views have the same context of the controller they are in.

I try `this.controller.get('some_variable');`
The output is undefined.
How to achieve it ???

Answer (score 1):

you need to use get to grab the controller, `this.get('controller.some_variable')`

Comment: hey...i did the same...check out this jsbin i made http://jsbin.com/fedak/3/edit ... the problem is in the init function of myview if i dont use this.get('controller.name') or  this.get('controller.lname') and write something like this.get('context') or any random string eg.alert('intialised')...the 'func' doesnt fire.It seems like you have to access the controller in the init to make the observers work.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this issue before, it has something to do with Ember not watching items that aren't ever accessed in their scope.  I'm not positive what your end game is with your view, but even just showing the item in the view would trigger it within it's scope.  http://jsbin.com/xojac/1/edit .  Though personally, I'd say that particular example is a bug.

Comment: Hey...thanks for the reply...the use case is like this.
I am making a visualisation app using d3js and ember.This is the graph i want to make [http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530] with some additional features.My design is like this.
1-First query  data from the backend
2- When you recieve the set a property in the controller.
3-The view has function like renderChart which observes any change on the property and draws the chart when the property changes.
4-When the user clicks on any of the internal bubbles...i want to create separate views for them ...like a tab..so that the user can destroy.